# where can I download unity assets without opening it in in unity.

Tags: unity, assets, asset-management

I'm browsing through my mobile phone and I need to download unity assets but unity asset store demands that I open the assets in unity directly. How or which site can I download it on my mobile and send it to my PC.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about using another party service and not about developing games.

Comment: I will use those assets to develop my game and I have already started developing my game with the standard assets but they are not enough

Comment: Why on earth would you ever do this, just use your pc to assess the assets.

Comment: I don't think you can.

Comment: On your PC, inside Unity :D

Comment: Kat.ph lol... Not a legal way, but it's possible if you've got a jailbroken phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible to do it outside of Unity3D. However, you could write a script that can pull the data from URLs of your choice in a Unity project and save it to a specific folder on your computer, that way you have the assets for later. Or, you could just have a dummy project and download all the assets that look useful for your current and possibly future projects as a means of storage for later use.
This isn't exactly what you want, but as far as I know, these are the only ways you could do it.